# Fluid - condition to check if value is NULL not working

Tags: fluid

I try to output my element only if the value of the property `fileEn` is NULL (`fileEn => NULL`)

```
<f:if condition="{file.fileEn}==NULL">
    <f:debug title='file'>{file}</f:debug>
</f:if>
```

However this is also showing me elements where fileEn is not `NULL`!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't check if something is `NULL` like this, it works like this:

Render only if property is **NULL**:

```
<f:if condition="{file.fileEn}">
    <f:then>

    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <!-- Property is NULL -->
        <f:debug title='file'>{file}</f:debug>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

Render only if property is **NOT NULL**:

```
<f:if condition="{file.fileEn}">
    <!-- Property is not NULL -->
    <f:debug title='file'>{file}</f:debug>
</f:if>
```

Comment: This is not correct, in your case, the property could also be "" (empty string) or FALSE, besides NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<f:if condition="{0:myVariable} == {0: NULL}'"></f:if>
```

Should also work

Comment: I can't verify, I don't work with fluid anymore (thx god), but thx for your contribution.

Comment: It works, but I am curious: why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `f:if` ViewHelper to test on `NULL`: using it, a [*falsy*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) but not `NULL` value would incorrectly be considered `NULL`, e.g. when `file.fileEn = "0"`.

Instead use the [`IsNullViewHelper`](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/blob/6.0.5/Classes/ViewHelpers/Condition/Variable/IsNullViewHelper.php):

```
<html
  xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
  xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers"
  data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true"
>

  <v:condition.variable.isNull value="{file.fileEn}">
    <f:then>
      is NULL
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      is not NULL
    </f:else>
  </v:condition.variable.isNull>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
<f:if condition="{file.fileEn}==">
    <f:debug title='file'>{file}</f:debug>
</f:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<v:condition.variable.isNull value="{newsItem.starttime}">
```

If I put something like this, the isNullViewHelper interprets this as a string, rather than as a variable...